# How to retrieve parameter from parameters.yml outside controller?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I need parameter from `parameters.yml` in `Command\ContainerAwareCommand` class. I don't see `$this->getParameter()` there.

Is there a simple way to retrieve parameter from `parameters.yml` outside controller?

Simpler than:
Write "friendly configuration", and put parameter `foo` into `config.yml`, and then retrieve param in `DependencyInjection\Extension::load()`, and set it: `$container->setParameter('foo', $foo)`, and finally in `Command\ContainerAwareCommand` retrieve it `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('foo')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply access to the container via:

```
... extends ContainerAwareCommand

...
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('my-params');
```

EDIT:

You can define your own custom parameters then import in the main config.yml files as example:

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@ApplicationBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml" }
```

hope this help

Comment: bonus question without bonus points: Can I keep parameters.yml in `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/` if I want AppBundle to be reusable? Is this file imported automatically? Cause I got Symfony exception `The parameter "foo" must be defined.`

Comment: hi @user6827096 of course, you can define the parameters in any place, then you import. I update my answer, hope this help

Comment: Note: ContainerAwareCommand is @deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use {@see Command} instead. Is possible also to access the container from the execute command itself doing: $container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();